# Link user image in user profile to image instead of user profile, drupal 7

Tags: drupal

When I visit a user profile with pictures in drupal the picture is linked to the user profile again. By clicking on the user image I'd like the full image to be shown e.g. by using lightbox. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything using profile2 for user profiles still if u cant hook the node of user
https://drupal.org/node/1911650